# how to cat on the results of a find operation + bash

Tags: arrays, bash, list, find, cat

```
$ a=$(find . -iname 'app.conf' 2>/dev/null)
```

The above gives me a list of files shown below:

```
$ echo "$a"
./etc/apps/dashboard_examples/default/app.conf
./etc/apps/framework/server/apps/homefx/splunkd/default/app.conf
.
.
.
```

How could I do a cat, and then grep, on each one of these files? 
Could I do cat on the first element in the array e.g. `cat a[1]`? Or how do I put a in a format like an array?

Comment: The value of the `$a` variable is not an array. It is a string. You cannot safely (in the face of files with spaces/newlines/etc. in their names) operate safely on the result of that `find` call. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for ways to safely and correctly operate on line-by-line data. Also notice that find can `-exec` commands on what it finds as it goes in case that's useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of `find` into an array using the `myarray=( $(command) )` expression:

```
a=( $(find . -iname 'app.conf' 2>/dev/null) )
# ^                                         ^
```

Then, print the first element with:

```
echo "${a[0]}"
```

Or if you want to `cat` it, say:

```
cat "${a[0]}"
```

---

If you want to execute a command on every result, you can use `-exec` as indicated by Etan Reisner in the comments:

```
find . -iname 'app.conf' -exec cat {} + 2>/dev/null
#                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `xargs` to do most of those things.

```
find . -iname 'app.conf' 2>/dev/null |
  xargs grep somepattern
```

You *can* operate safely on filenames with spaces by using `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `xargs`.

See `man xargs` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

How about using for?

```
> for a_file in $a; do cat $f | grep something; done
```

Comment: Not safe for files with spaces, newlines or shell metacharacter in their names.

Comment: I read your comment and found "find exec" is much more safe and convenient, thanks!